# Error on parsing json with new line character

Tags: json, flutter, dart, retrofit

I trying to use `retrofit` on `flutter` & I am using [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) to serialize.

In `JSON` I have:

```
{
  "date": "07.12.2020",
  "header": "Test header",
  "text": "line one 
line two,
line 3"
    }
```

With new line chars inline.
The new lines on "text" part

Because of these new line chars, I have an error by parsing

> unexpected character on line...

But the same `JSON` successfully parsed on android.

Are any ways to replace or solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Multi-line text is not allowed in JSON. You need to convert new lines using `\n`. Then you can parse it easily.

Comment: but in Java same JSON parsed with gson successfully